# Preventing File upload by everyone

Tags: php, security, file-upload, nginx

I create an image server by nginx and php.

Now, I can upload images(png,jpg,jpeg) through the url : http://image.hostname.com/upload/directory/to/store .

Nginx will rewrite the url to execute a php script. The file type, size will be checked, then the directory /directory/to/store will be created if it is not existed. Finally, the file will be stored in.

Now , I am thinking of that, if anyone knows the url , he can upload any number of images to the server. It is terrible. So, how to deal with this situation.? Thanks!

Comment: why not just password protect the folder?

Comment: @Fred-ii-  please make it more specific.